# svchost.exe writes registry on startup with revoked permissions

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, svchost, process-monitor

I made a post recently about some program changing the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxySettingsPerUser` registry key every boot from 1 to 0. I found out this program was svchost.exe (`C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k NetSvcs -p -s iphlpsvc` command specifically) using Process Monitor's Boot Logger.

I revoked SYSTEM's Full Control permissions over that key, disabled svchost in `services.msc` and added a shortcut into my startup folder to reset the key on boot - to no avail, looking back in Process Monitor shows svchost.exe overwriting the key to 0.

My startup script: `C:\Windows\regedit.exe /s "D:\Thrith\Desktop\proxy.reg"`

proxy.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxySettingsPerUser"=dword:00000001
```

Screencap of the permissions ('Rendszergazdák' means Admins and they are the only ones who have permission to write it):

[image]

Process Monitor (The highlighted value is the first one where its set to 0, the ones before are all 1, like I left it): [image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you cannot lock system out of anything, it is the locks. if you could, you'd break your OS. Windows is not designed that way.

Comment: @FrankThomas I know I can't, but I was hoping at least I can limit its sub processes to leave that key alone, otherwise not sure what system permissions are for.

Comment: I think you need to change the GPO setting "Make proxy settings per-machine (rather than per-user)" or perhaps unset the machine proxy address in gpupdate. the setting you are trying to manipulate is dependent on other settings, so its likely that you have an inconcsistency and the IP helper service is trying to fix it the best way it knows how, and thats not the way you want. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-ie-clientnetworkprotocolimplementation-hklmproxyserver

Comment: @FrankThomas I checked Make proxy settings per-machine (rather than per-user), found one under `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\` but that's already not configured, which means it should allow per user. I am not sure what I'm supposed to do with the information in the link you provided.

Comment: My guess is that you have conflicting settings between machine-wide proxy configuration, and the system is resolving the issue with a machine config. look for signs you have configuration specific to machine-wide proxy like the reg value  "HKLMProxyServer"

Comment: @FrankThomas I had one setting changed in Group Policy which was disabled, so I changed it to not configured, but that didn't affect it. All the other group policies seem to be set to default